# C++ Memory Writing for the PS3

Tags: c++, c

I'm learning how to hack PS3 games, where I need to edit what is stored at certain memory addresses. Here is an example of what I see people do to to achieve this:

```
*(char*)0x1786418 = 0x40;
```

This line of code turns on super speed for COD Black Ops II.

I'm not 100% sure what is going on here. I know that `0x1786418` is the address and `0x40` sets the value at that address. But I'm not so sure what `*(char*)` does and how does `0x40` turn on super speed?

An explanation of this syntactically and how it turns on super speed would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: *how does 0x40 turn on super speed?* Find someone who's reverse-engineered it. That's super specific to CoD, and probably to this specific hack.

Comment: You're really diving in the deep-end here. This is quite a straightforward line of code so if you're having trouble understanding it, you should work your way up to it by learning the basics. To give you a basic answer...someone reverse engineered the memory address of some variable which might be added to a player's position at each step during movement. If you change the value of that variable (which is what this line does), then each step of movement will now add this new value onto the players position. Similarly, changing it to a lower value may be used to slow your player down.

Comment: I don't think that your question about *(char*) can be explained in a short answer. Just read something about the C programming language (a book maybe?). And about the exact value of 0x40, that's specific to the way the game was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider understanding the basics of the programming language *before* you try to go into reverse-engineering. That's definitely an advanced topic that you don't want to use as a way to get started. It'll make things unnecessarily more difficult for you.

> I'm not 100% sure what is going on here. I know that 0x1786418 is the address and 0x40 sets the value at that address.

This is as much as anyone here might be able to tell you, unless the person who reverse-engineered the software shows up here and explains it.

> But I'm not so sure what `*(char*)` does

This is a way to take the address and *interpret* it as a pointer to a byte (`char`s in C are 1 byte of memory) and then the outside `*` dereferences the pointer to allow the value referenced by the pointer to be modified, in this case, set to the value `0x40`.

> and how does `0x40` turn on super speed?

This is very specific to the game itself. Someone must've figured out where data about player movement speed is stored in memory (specifically for the PS3) and is updating it this way.

Something like this could easily break by a simple patch because code changes can make certain things end up at different addresses, requiring additional reverse-engineering efforts.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is seing this and wants to know how to set prestiges or enable red boxes or what not ill explain how (MW3 Will be my example)

so for a prestige it would be like  `*(char*)0x01C1947C = 20;`
that would set prestige 20 if you dont understand for 20 you can either do 20 or 0x14 would also equal prestige 20 say you want prestige 12 you could do 12 or 0xC
if you dont know how just search prestige you want then in hex :)

now for stuff like red boxes (assuming you know about bools / if statements and voids im not going to cover them only how you would set it)

now you would do for red boxes (enable) ps. bytesOn can be called anything

```
char bytesOn[] = { 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
write_process(0x65D14, bytesOn, sizeof(bytesOn));
whateverYourBoolIsCalled = true;
```

now to turn it off works the same except you have to get the other bytes :)

ill add 1 more example if you want to set a name in a sprx

`char name[] = { "name here" };
write_process(0x01BBBC2C, name, sizeof(name));`

there is shorter ways of doing this but i think its the best way to understand doing it this way :) 
so ye this has been my tut :)